# Como Dejar una columa de titulos en un datagrid? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid

agrego los datos desde una consulta a sql pero quisiera dejar titulos en el datagrid, ya los intente agregar desde el mismo datagrid pero al traer la informacion de la consulta recorre la informacion unas celdas.... (Dejo imagen)

Con este codigo traigo los datos de la db

```
private void DetalleTicket()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Cantidad as Cant, CodigoArticulo, UnidadDeVenta, Descripcion, PrecioUnitario, " +
                "Importe FROM DETALLE_TICKETS WHERE CodigoTicket = @codigoticket", con.LeerCadena());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigoticket", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_operacion.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DgvTicket.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

[image: Safado]

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: el datasource no te permite mandar cada uno de los datos a una columna en especifico, tiene que usar SqlDataReader para poder enviar cada dato a una columna en especifico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con esto

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnectio("tuconexion");
            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select Cantidad as Cant, CodigoArticulo, UnidadDeVenta, Descripcion, PrecioUnitario, " +
            "Importe FROM DETALLE_TICKETS WHERE CodigoTicket = @codigoticket", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigoticket", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_operacion.Text;
            SqlDataReader read;
            con.Open();
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                int row = dataGridAllAcounts.Rows.Add();
                dataGridAllAcounts.Rows[row].Cells["NombreColumna"].Value = read.GetString(0);
                dataGridAllAcounts.Rows[row].Cells["NombreColumna"].Value = read.GetString(1);
                dataGridAllAcounts.Rows[row].Cells["NombreColumna"].Value = read.GetString(2);
                dataGridAllAcounts.Rows[row].Cells["NombreColumna"].Value = read.GetInt32(3);
            }
```

De esta manera tu puedes mandarler directamente un dato a tu columna, no puedo ver tu imagen.

Comment: ingrese el code pero al querer correrlo me mando que no se puede convertir un dato double a una cadena... 

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.'

te dejo la imagen aqui 
https://ibb.co/MnjzMjp esto es lo que me mueve..

Comment: en tu query cual es el dato double? porque yo obviamente use datos de ejemplo, tienes que cambiarlos a corde a tus datos

Comment: las imagenes no las puedo ver, estoy desde un seervidor privado y me bloquea el link

Comment: o bien mandalos todos como string a las columnas asi read.GetString(#posiciondelquery);

Comment: int row = DgvTicket.Rows.Add();
                DgvTicket.Rows[row].Cells["Cantidad"].Value = read.GetString(0);
                DgvTicket.Rows[row].Cells["Articulo"].Value = read.GetString(1);

En la primera columna es donde me manda el error

Comment: intenta asi para cada uno cambia lo ultimo despues del "=" DgvTicket.Rows[row].Cells["Articulo"].Value = read["CodigoArticulo"].ToString();

Comment: Con eso me lo mando .. Muchísimas gracias!! ahora a seguir con esto